# Global Operator "->" overload C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload "->" operator globally for pointers. Is it possible?

```
A *var1 = new A(21);
int x = var1->someInt;
```

In that code it has to be triggered when reaching "var1"s "someInt" variable.

Actually I am trying to check the pointer before reaching its members. Also, I am trying to implement this system on a written code, so I don't want to change too much thing in the actual code.

Comment: [This operator overload reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) should tell you what you need to know. Thinking about it logically would also answer your question (how would an ***object member-access*** operator work without an object?).

Comment: What would you expect this operator to do without taking any arguments?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the language definition requires `operator->` to be a member function.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to overload "->" operator globally. Is it possible?

No it is impossible.

Perhaps you might define a "root" class in your library or program (which would define that operator `->`), and have all your classes inherit from it.

BTW, I am not sure you will be able to define your `isPointerValid` function in all cases (including the address of valid automatic variables of any class type), and efficiently.

There are many cases where you could not define such a function (e.g. `union`-s used in [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) types; you don't easily know what member of a union is currently active. arbitrary casts; ...); .

For existing code and classes, the builtin meaning of `->` (which you usually cannot redefine) has already been used to compile the code using them.

Comment: Good idea, declaring a root class, but I am trying to use this system on a written code. So I cannot change that much thing.

Comment: That should go into your question (and is not possible). You need to improve your question to explain  more the real motivations and context.

Answer (score 2):

As described in C++17 standard draft in section 16.5.6 (emphasis mine):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function that has **at least one parameter whose type
>   is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to
>   an enumeration**.

Hence, it is not possible to overload an operator which doesn't take any arguments.